# Avoid InvalidOperationException using Generic Collection in multithread application (foreach)

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, foreach, invalidoperationexception

*.NET Framework 3.5*

I have two threads that using the same generic collection. One thread loop through the collection using the `foreach` statement:

```
while(HaveToContinue)
{
   // Do work 1

   try
   {
      foreach(var item in myDictionary)
      {
         // Do something with/to item
      }

      // Do work 2 (I need to complete the foreach first)
   }
   catch(InvalidOperationException)
   {
   }
}
```

At the same time the other thread modify the collection:

```
// The following line causes the InvalidOperationException (in the foreach)
myDictionary.Remove(...);
```

So, is there a way to avoid this `InvalidOperationException`? If I could avoid this exception I could complete my work (work 1 + work 2) all times, instead, every time I catch the exception, I can't finish the work.

I thought to use a `ManualResetEvent` object, something like this:

```
while(HaveToContinue)
{
   // Do work 1

   try
   {
      myResetEvent.Reset();
      foreach(var item in myDictionary)
      {
         // Do something with/to item
      }
      myResetEvent.Set();

      // Do work 2 (I need to complete the foreach first)
   }
   catch(InvalidOperationException)
   {
   }
}
```

And every time the other thread modify the collection:

```
// Expect the foreach is completed
myResetEvent.WaitOne();
// And then modify the collection
myDictionary.Remove(...);
```

But probably there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4, you should use the `ConcurrentBag` or `ConcurrentDictionary` class instead, which are thread-safe.

If you're using an earlier version, then the easiest (albeit inefficient) solution would be to use a `lock`. You could instantiate this as a plain object:

```
private readonly object sync = new object();
```

Then, when you need to access the list, acquire the lock first:

```
while (HaveToContinue)
{
   // Do work 1

   lock (sync)
   {
      foreach (var item in myDictionary)
      {
         // Do something with/to item
      }
   }

   // Do work 2 (I need to complete the foreach first)
}
```

Similarly when modifying the collection, acquiring the *same* lock:

```
lock (sync)
{
    myDictionary.Remove(...);
}
```

If the amount of work you have to do on each item is substantial, then it would be more efficient to first obtain a local copy of the dictionary, release the lock, and then proceed to iterate over the said copy, allowing the racing thread to modify the global dictionary:

```
while (HaveToContinue)
{
   // Do work 1

   Dictionary<Key,Value> localDictionary;

   lock (sync)
   {
      localDictionary = new Dictionary<Key,Value>(myDictionary);
   }

   foreach (var item in localDictionary)
   {
      // Do something with/to item
   }

   // Do work 2 (I need to complete the foreach first)
}
```

Comment: If this is the inefficient solution there is also an efficient one?

Comment: Using the new dictionary if I change the item the change is not reflected on the original collection.

Comment: If the dictionary's values are of a reference type, then yes, changes would be reflected to the original collection, since both local and original collections would contain references to the same objects.

Comment: In fact, if they are reference type... This is the problem: I can't ensure this. Anyway +1 for now, I'll test your solution.

Comment: If they are not, it typically isn't an issue either, since value types are generally immutable.

Comment: It's a choice: the first `lock` approach makes it (almost) single-threaded, the `localDictionary` approach can be costly and it aggravates the (logical) race-condition: processing items that the other thread already removed.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Both valid points. The `lock` approach is suitable when the respective threads are performing a lot of work other than just accessing the collection. The second approach assumes that the logical race condition is benign; if it were not, there would typically need to be other synchronization mechanisms in place anyway (for example, to ensure that an item _has_ been removed before starting the loop again).